# How to mark the specific date in dynamically generated JavaScript calendar using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

On my website, I have four calendar generated by JavaScript as a table. I wondering how to mark specific date (in each calendar separately) using JSON file - I want to add proper class to cells which store date mentioned in JSON file.

Why I thought about using JSON? 
Because I want it would be as simple as possible - person who is going to edit those calendars are not a programmer.

How and where I should implement JSON to achieve this effect?
How to tell my calendar that, for example, 25.03.2017 - 30.03.2017 should be marked in calendar nr 1 ?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
function calendar (date, config) {
    config = config || {};

    var Y = date.getFullYear();
    var M = date.getMonth();
    var D = date.getDate();

    var daysInMonth = new Date(Y, M + 1, 0).getDate();
    var daysInPreviousMonth = new Date(Y, M, 0).getDate();
    var monthStart = new Date(Y, M, 0);
    var firstDay = monthStart.getDay();

    var today = new Date();
    var todayY = today.getFullYear();
    var todayM = today.getMonth();
    var todayD = today.getDate();

    // Highlight current date
    if (config.highlightToday) {
        config.highlightToday = Y === todayY && M === todayM;
    }
    // Generate calendar table
    var s = '<table>';

    if (config.showHead) {
        s += '<tr class="first-row"><th colspan="7" class="month-name">' + Y + ' ' + calendar.monthNames[M] + '</th></tr>';
        s += '<tr><th class="day-name">' + calendar.weekDayNames.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';
    }

    var d = -firstDay + 1;
    var rows = 6;

    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        s += '<tr>';

        for (var col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
            s += '<td';
            var cl = [];

            if (config.highlightToday && d === todayD) {
                cl.push('today');
            }

            if (d <= 0 || d > daysInMonth) {
                cl.push('surrounding');
            }

            if (cl.length) {
                s += ' class="' + cl.join(' ') + '"';
            }

            s += '>';

            if (config.showSurroundingMonths && d <= 0) {
                s += daysInPreviousMonth + d;
            }

            if (d > 0 && d <= daysInMonth) {
                s += d;
            }

            if (config.showSurroundingMonths && d > daysInMonth) {
                s += d % daysInMonth;
            }

            d++;

            s += '</td>';
        }
        s += '</tr>';
    }

    s += '</table>';
    return s;
}


calendar.weekDayNames = ['P', 'W', 'Ś', 'C', 'P', 'S', 'N'];
calendar.monthNames = ['Styczeń', 'Luty', 'Marzec',
                       'Kwiecień', 'Maj', 'Czerwiec',
                       'Lipiec', 'Sierpnień', 'Wrzesień',
                       'Październik', 'Listopad', 'Grudzień'];

// -------------------------------------------

var date = new Date();

function updateCalendar(cal) {
    cal.innerHTML = calendar(date, {
        highlightDate: true, 
        highlightToday: true, 
        showHead: true, 
        showSurroundingMonths: true
    });
}

updateCalendar(calendar1);
updateCalendar(calendar2);
updateCalendar(calendar3);
updateCalendar(calendar4);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to store the JSON with the selected data on a server or how do you indent on using that JSON?

Comment: I want to have JSON file in which you could write selected data to specific calendar. Selected dates should be visual marked on a website in proper calendar.

Comment: You could use a data structure like `{calendar1: date1, calendar2: date2, calendar3: date3, calendar4: date4}` and save this in a JSON file.

Comment: Yes, it would be great, but it isn't clear for me how to use this solution in practice.

Comment: You don't know how to store the JSON or how to read it or how to serialize it? I don't know where are you exactly blocked. What is the purpose of that JSON?

Comment: I don't know how to use the JSON in this case. I thought edit a JSON file is the simplest way to mark a specific date - especially for someone who don't want write a code - that is a purpose, I have a one file which I write some date, then table cell which store this date gets class which means 'this date is busy' thats's all.